# Context-dependent log level in Python

Tags: python, logging, thread-local

I'm prototyping a web application framework in Python (mostly for educative purposes) and I'm stuck on one feature I've wanted for such a long time: per-route log level.

The goal of this feature is to identify some specific entry points for which we're performing diagnostics.  For example, I want to track what's going on when callers hit `POST /sessions/login`.  Now, I want to get 100% of log entries for code hit by request processing for this URL.  And this means everything, including whatever goes on in 3rd-party applications.

**Example**: fictional application has two routes: `/sessions/login` and `/sessions/info`.  Both request handlers hit the same database code in package `users`, which uses logger `myapp.users.db`.  Request processing for `/sessions/login` should emit log messages on logger `myapp.users.db`, but request processing for `/sessions/info` should not.

The problem is that this doesn't fit well with Python's logging library, which decomposes logging in a hierarchical fashion, which is nice for layering (e.g. controlling the log level by application layers).

What I really want is a context-dependent log level.  The natural implementation that comes to mind is something that makes `logger.getEffectiveLevel()` return a thread-local log level (with debug middleware conditionally lowering the log level to debug if the request URL is subject to debugging).  However, I'm looking at the [logging flow](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) in the Python documentation, and I don't understand how to implement this using any of the many different types of configuration hooks.

---

**Question**: how would you implement a context-dependent log level in Python?

---

**Update**: I found a partial solution.

```
context = threading.local()

class ContextualLogger(logging.Logger):
    def getEffectiveLevel(self):
        global context
        level = getattr(context, 'log_level', logging.NOTSET)
        if level == logging.NOTSET:
            level = super(ContextualLogger, self).getEffectiveLevel()
        return level

logging.setLoggerClass(ContextualLogger)
```

However, this doesn't work for the root logger.  Any ideas?

---

**Update**: it's also possible to monkey patch the `getEffectiveLevel()` function.

```
context = threading.local()

# Monkey patch "getEffectiveLevel()" to consult the current setting in the
# `context.log_level` thread-local storage.  If that value is present, use
# it to override the current value; else, compute the level using the usual
# infrastructure.
default_getEffectiveLevel = logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel
def patched_getEffectiveLevel(self):
    level = getattr(context, 'log_level', logging.NOTSET)
    if level == logging.NOTSET:
        level = default_getEffectiveLevel(self)
    return level
logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel = patched_getEffectiveLevel
```

Now, this works even for the root logger.  I have to admit that I'm a little uncomfortable with monkey patching this function, but then again it falls back onto the usual infrastructure so it's actually not as dirty as it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a `logging.Filter` which is attached to your loggers (or handlers) which uses the context to either drop the event (by returning `False` from the `filter` method) or allow the event to be logged (by returning `True` from the `filter` method).

Though not exactly for your use case, I illustrated use of filters with thread-local context in [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/configuring-logging-for-web.html).

Comment: Since that solution only allows me to apply a tighter log level than the one already enforced (the filter can apply the `logging.WARNING` when the current level is `logging.DEBUG`, but not the other way around), I suspect I'll have to configure all loggers to the `logging.DEBUG` level and then control the log level only from the thread variable then?  Contrast this with the partial solution in my questions, which allows you to replace the effective log level completely, regardless of the current level.