# Can a wrapper/decorator function in Python disable all logging inside the code it wraps

Tags: python, logging, python-decorators

I want to decorate/wrap a function and prevent the logging of all logs from within that function's scope.

```
def prevent_logs_wrapper(func):
    ...
    ...
    ...

@prevent_logs_wrapper
def some_logs():
    logger.info('Log an info msg')
    logger.warning('Log a warning msg')
```

and instead of this output

```
[INFO] Log an info msg
[WARNING] Log an warning msg
```

we won't get any logs.

Comment: Yes. You can set `logger.setLevel(logging.FATAL)` and then restore the level when the function exists. However, not that loggers are usually shared across different threads so if your application depends on threads this is not going to work.

Comment: My code uses threads, so I can't completely block the logging. I am looking into filtering the logs based on the stack that is called by the wrapper. Block everything that is called by the wrapper. There is a logging function "findCaller" which might work.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17522901/315168

Answer (score 1):

There is no such possibility in the logging, but it is available in the [Polog](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog) library. Install it:

```
$ pip install polog
```

And use the [unlog decorator](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-unlog) for your functions:

```
from polog import log, unlog

@unlog
def function():
    log("some text") # It won't work!
```

The Polog is more powerful than standard logging, try to use it.